# What was the first film to have a fight on top of a moving train?

Tags: first-appearance, cinema-history

The earliest I could locate was a Mexican film El Tren fantasma as described [here](http://thebioscope.net/2010/11/20/three-mexican-silents/).

[The General (1926)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_General_%281926_film%29) starring Buster Keaton was known for its action in a train, but I am unable to reliably establish if there was a fight on top of a moving train.

Is there any older movie which has such a fight?

Comment: You can download a free version of _The General_ at [archive.org](http://archive.org/details/TheGeneral1926)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The oldest I know is "The Great Train Robbery" (1903).

There is a [youtube clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X19_zg1QygY), see scene 4, approx. in minute 4ff

There are more information about the film at:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Train_Robbery_%28film%29)
- [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0017925/)

Comment: And the first narrative film: http://www.filmsite.org/grea.html